# An issue with rangesearch (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to find the nearest neighbors using the rangesearch function in matlab. I have been doing this for a long time and Now I started facing some unknown issues.

I have previously run rangesearch for huge sizes ( 6 Mil.) and was successful. Now I was trying to run it for 0.3 M and it is taking forever and it consumes ~ 50 GB of memory. Could anyone help ?

I have attached the test file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1elSabMbRnwWjNjbUEzUGt5TlE/view?usp=sharing) and the simple code is given below -

```
Glist =dlmread('test');
[idx,dist]= rangesearch(Glist,Glist,12);
```

Comment: This problem may be related to a bug that is extensivelly discussed in a matlab [fórum topic][1]. I have experienced the same problem which is after a expensive process that tooks a lot of memory, matlab never turn back to be like before, it becomes very slow even after close and computer restart. I have also tried to remove matlab.prf which didn't solve. [1]: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/111060-after-allocating-a-large-variable-and-crashing-matlab-is-forever-slow

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, but couldn't put it in the comment section as I have less points.

Anyway, are you sure you have to search each and every point in Glist? As it has around .3M points, it's going to take some time. And of course, it going to occupy a huge memory space because for each point one cell is create which contains points ranging from some hundreds to thousands. So, I would suggest start with small bunch of points and keep increasing the size of the bunch. For example,

```
tic; [idx,dist]= rangesearch(Glist,Glist(1:50000,:),12);toc
```

tic-toc combination gives you the time elapsed. By the way, on my machine the above command took ~80 seconds. And, I didn't want to go beyond that as the time is going to increase along with the memory.